# Microphone input also picks up all system sounds (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, microphone, ubuntu-22.04

I use an Arturia MiniFuse 2 audio interface to connect my microphone and headphones to my computer, but the microphone input in Zorin (an Ubuntu derivative) *also captures system audio*. This happens both in the live environment and my local installation. The issue does not occur in Windows, so it must be a software issue.

`pavucontrol` lists two (relevant) inputs:

- Monitor of MiniFuse 2 Analog Surround 4.0 -> Includes only system audio, as expected.
- MiniFuse 2 Multichannel -> Includes both my microphone's input **and** system audio. This should only include my microphone.

Interestingly, the sound settings menu has my Output Device set as MiniFuse 2 (as expected), but the Input Device is *blank*, and does not list any MiniFuse-related devices. I can still record my voice in Sound Recorder using the MiniFuse, though.

How can I separate my microphone and system audio?

**Edit:** I have done a little more testing and the same issue occurs on another machine with Zorin 17 installed. I dual-booted Manjaro on that machine and it works as expected, **so it's definitely something wrong with either Ubuntu or Zorin**.
Is there anything I can copy from the Manjaro installation to make this work? Some config files maybe? I don't know where to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation, it appears as if the rear two "surround" channels are actually acting like a loopback. **Moving the output fade slider in the sound settings all the way to "front" fixes the issue.**

This isn't a perfect solution, however. It still doesn't present itself as an input device in the Settings application (despite working just fine), and the fade slider doesn't save its position if you reopen Settings (but it continues to work as if it was). Functionally, it's perfect. But the user experience is definitely not good.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a utility such as [JACK](https://jackaudio.org/), which acts as audio patch-board, or one of the [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/jack-audio-connection-kit/?platform=linux).

Having used these utilities, I found setup a bit confusing, but eventually these patch-boards *can* be set to route inputs to desired processors and outputs.

Comment: My distro already comes with PipeWire installed, which I believe is a replacement for JACK. I've installed a few different tools to view the graph (Helvum, qpwgraph) but none of them show the MiniFuse as an audio input/output, only as a MIDI device.